# How to connect docker image to a docker-composed network

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yml` that defines a database and API image for development but I also have a separate `Dockerfile` that builds the API for an AWS deploy. For testing locally before deploying I want to bring up the db image with `docker-compose` and then connect the API deployable image to this database instance. This is failing with `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host ''db'' (-2)")` indicating the hostname doesn't exist.

Here's the relavant `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./db/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        target: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - type: volume
        source: mysql-data
        target: /var/lib/mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: toor
    networks:
      - backend
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
volumes:
  mysql-data:
networks:
  backend:
```

The command I'm running to start the API deployable image is: `docker run -p 80:80 --env-file .env --network='<app>_backend' <image>`

With Django database configuration:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
        'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
        'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
        'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
    }
}
```

and my `.env` file being:

```
RDS_DB_NAME='django'
RDS_USERNAME='root'
RDS_PASSWORD='toor'
RDS_HOSTNAME='db'
RDS_PORT=3306
```

Is there something I need to configure for DNS to work properly here or what could be going wrong?

Comment: That error message looks like the single quotes in the `.env` file are being interpreted as part of the host name – it's trying to connect to a host named "`'db'`" including the quotes.  Does removing those quotes help?

Comment: `There is no special handling of quotation marks. This means that they are part of the VAL.` => https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/#syntax-rules

Comment: @DavidMaze @Zeitounator That's exactly it. I removed all quotation marks for the values in `.env` and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Zeitounator's [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/#syntax-rules), removing all quotations in `.env` fixed my issue.

> These syntax rules apply to the .env file:
>
> - Compose expects each line in an env file to be in VAR=VAL format.
> - Lines beginning with # are processed as comments and ignored.
> - Blank lines are ignored.
> - **There is no special handling of quotation marks. This means that they are part of the VAL.**

New `.env`:

```
RDS_DB_NAME=django
RDS_USERNAME=root
RDS_PASSWORD=toor
RDS_HOSTNAME=db
RDS_PORT=3306
```